# Dynamically create a link and open it in same iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a link that is being dynamically created with url params and all sort of good stuff in my javascript.

I am then obviously trying to open that page. I would like to open it within the same iframe, but anything I try keeps opening it in a new tab (can't do it this way because I loose all context and data).

I have tried

```
window.open(url, '#iframeId'); 
window.open(url);
window.open(url, '_top'); //This kind of worked, but overtook the whole window ignoring the iframe
```

Any ideas? Most of what I saw when I searched was coming from the html side and I don't have access to changing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist you need to set your `<iframe name="test">` name like this and
than use `window.open('www.google.co.in', "test")` this

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `src` of the `iframe`.

```
$("#iframeId").prop("src", url);
```

Without jQuery you could go for:

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').src = url;
```

Here is a jsfiddle with some kind of the functionality you search for.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MALuP/)